# Google Maps - user to pinpoint a location

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, mapping, geolocation

Is it possible to allow users of my website to mark places on a map I display using Google Maps API? I need to then save that location coordinates to a db.

I've been looking through the google maps API, I found that I can use the web service to do searches like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Maine,+United+States&output=json&oe=utf8\&sensor=false&key=my_key
```

But I am not sure it's working on a house number level (which I need it to) and I'm not sure how to display a 'did you mean?' to the user when he misspells the address..

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There is nice example of what you want

http://digitalinspiration.com/community/location.html

Using code like this:

```
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;

function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
 map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl()); 
 map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl()); 
 map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 14);
 map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    GEvent.addListener(map, "click", clicked);
  }
}

function showAddress(address) {
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.getLatLng(
      address,
      function(point) {
        if (!point) {
          alert("We're sorry but '" + address + "' cannot be found on Google Maps. Please try again.");
        } else {
         map.panTo(point); 
    }
  });
}
}

function clicked(overlay, latlng) {
  if (latlng) {
    geocoder.getLocations(latlng, function(addresses) {
      if(addresses.Status.code != 200) {
        alert("reverse geocoder failed to find an address for " + latlng.toUrlValue());
      }
      else {
        address = addresses.Placemark[0];
        var myHtml = address.address;
        map.openInfoWindow(latlng, myHtml);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks awesome, although I can't find any streets in Israel for example, where I know Google Maps are providing street level mapping.. Is there anyway to load the maps in a way that will allow me to see street level mapping?

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/cs-CZ/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeId

Comment: Ok, this is really weird, I can see everything to street level on every other place i've looked (using the top link you gave me), but can't see it in Israel. Can you?

Comment: I see an Israel street map on maps.google.com, you probably have to find right overlay ID.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a site which uses Maps API for displaying events across the globe (300+ of sport events), so yes, it's possible. The geocoding works really well in general (just as on the Maps site). I've used it with a Map display where the user can drag a marker to adjust the exact location, then saved the coordinates. In this way, you won't really need a 'did you mean?'-type box.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote and open-sourced an [SDK for Google's Geocoding API](https://github.com/JWT-OSS/Google-Geocoding-PHP-SDK-Unofficial) which should making working with the API a bit easier.

Note that this is for the **v3** API, whereas in the code above you're referencing the **v2** API (which is now deprecated)

The API itself will auto-correct typos in the input. So if you wanted to make sure that the user entered a location that was actually a street address, you'd do that like so (with my SDK)

```
$service = new GoogleGeocodeServiceV3( new CurlCommunicator() );

$response = $service->geocode( '123 Any Street, USA' );

if ( $response->isValid() && $response->hasResults() )
{
  // Is it a street-level result?
  if ( $response->assertType( GoogleGeocodeResponseV3::ACT_STREET_ADDRESS ) )
  {
    // Street-level address found
  } else {
    // Not a street-level address
  }
}
```

If their typo was so egregious that the API didn't find anything, than `$response->hasResults()` would return `false` (or, `count( $response )` would be `0`)

Comment: Your SDK looks really nice, does it also draw the map and pinpoints the requested address? From what I can see it just 'autocorrects' and checks if the location is valid, am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The lat/lng information is part of the response as well, and available through the SDK.  The documentation has more info.